# How to get the size of inverted index in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I think the title is pretty self-explanatory. As far as I can tell [`indices-stats`](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-stats.html) only returns the number of documents in the collection, not the number of tokens/terms.

#### EDIT:

Here's a bit more information about my index; it contains medical publications indexed over with the following mapping:

```
{
    u'papers': {
        u'properties': {
            u'article_abstract': {
                u'type': 
                u'string'
            },
            u'article_sections': {
                u'type': 
                u'string'
            },
            u'article_text': {
                u'type': 
                u'string'
            },
            u'article_title': {
                u'type': 
                u'string'
            },
            u'keyword_group': {
                u'type': 
                u'string'
            },
            u'references': {
                u'type': 
                u'string'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm looking for is a way to get the number of **unique terms** across the all fields in the index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file size of an index can be fetched from the `store` field of the same [indices-stats](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-stats.html) api, such as

`{ "docs": { "count": 1886, "deleted": 1557 }, "store": { "size_in_bytes": 519544594, "throttle_time_in_millis": 0 }, ...(skipped)`

But if you want the total token amount of an index, I don't think there exist such an api since it does not mean much. If you want the number, I think you need to calculate by using `script_field` and `aggregation`.

**EDIT:**

According your schema, the token count can be calculated as follow:

```
{
"query" : {
    "match_all" : { }
},
 "aggs" : {
    "summation" : { "sum" : {  "script" : "doc['article_abstract'].values.length+doc['article_sections'].values.length" } }
}
}
```

The query above just calculates the token size of field 'article_abstracts' and 'article_sections' as u see. I am not sure there are any way to not "iterate" all fields. But anyway, you can continue from this.

Comment: thanks, this is perfect! I have to switch form .length to .size() though!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to return the unique terms from an index, you need to query it. To return the **count** - you need to use Value Count Aggregation - http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-valuecount-aggregation.html:

```
{
    "aggs" : {
        "grades_count" : { "value_count" : { "field" : "grade" } }
    }
}
```

If you want to return the **distinct terms** for a given field you would perform an aggregated search like this:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/yourindex/_search?pretty" -d'
{
    "aggs" : {
        "aggname" : {
            "terms" : { "field" : "YourFieldName" }
        }
    }
}'
```

Obviously if you wanted to return the distinct terms over an entire index, we would need some information on your schema.

Comment: I'm looking for the number of distinct terms **across the index**. I've added some information about the mapping of my index in the original question.